# how to add a .remove extension for a zip file

Tags: zip

I am trying to send a project file via Gmail and i am having trouble sending the zip file with a .exe file in it. How can i change the zip file to fileName.zip.remove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `+=` operator:

```
string filename = "fileName.zip";
filename += ".remove";
```

The last line is equivalent to:

```
filename = filename + ".remove";
```

---

A common problem when sending e-mails is that antiviruses reject .exe files, even when they are included in zip files. You can hide the exe file in zip file if you encrypt this file. This involves giving a password to the zip file. You can write down this password in the e-mail text. The antivirus is not smart enough to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest actually changing the name of the exe file itself and rezipping it and sending it. But to change the name of the file itself, you should be able to right-click on it, and rename should be an option. Just type in .remove, ignore the warning about file extensions if it shows up, and send it! :)